# Move files from Ubuntu to windows or change windows files(media) files with ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

I have Installed Ubuntu 18.04 last month beside windows 10 and already I installed kubuntu on my Ubuntu instead of default gnome. Now when I use Ubuntu I have access to window files but I can't move a file from Ubuntu allocated space to windows allocated space or change a text file (for example) that is in windows allocated space from Ubuntu but if I reboot to windows and then reboot to Ubuntu then I have full access to windows files from Ubuntu ( change or cut...) . Now I wanna found a way that whitout rebooting to windows I have full access to windows files then I don't need to rebooting my system two times every time I wanna use it . but I have no idea how to to do it... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a quite new user but I think you should mount the windows partition on read and write mode.

I did not find the exact solution but it must be there :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountingWindowsPartitions